# Powshell Binary Module

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-module

I have a powershell module with a base class that derives from cmdlet and all of my cmdlets derive from that.  Import-module cannot see any of my classes that indirectly derive from cmdlet. Do I need to add a manifest to support this structure.

Comment: Please show some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely one of both of the following problems:

- The classes are not `public`
- The classes are not decorated with `[CmdletAttribute]`

Here's a minimal, functioning cmdlet:

```
[Cmdlet(Verb = VerbsCommon.Get, Noun = "Answer")]
public class GetAnswerCommand : PSCmdlet {
    public override void EndProcessing() {
        WriteObject(42);
    }
}
```

Use `import-module` with `-verbose` to see information about what's visible. For binary modules, you do not need a manifest (psd1).

Comment: The derived classes constructors were not public.

Answer (score 0):

Did you place the module in `$env:PSModulePath`?

`Import-Module` will see modules placed at the above path only. Optionally, you can add the path of your module to `$env:PSModulePath`.

Comment: Or give the full path to Import-Module

Comment: Oh, yes. That is another option.